# JS how to do something only once

Tags: javascript, function

For example:

```
// run this:
alert('Loading...');

// dont run this again:
alert('Loading...');
```

I don't want to ever repeat that.
How can I do this with convenience (preferably without using booleans)?

Comment: This question would be more answerable if you showed the context:  what's currently causing the code to run multiple times?

Comment: Based on what you currently have, the most obvious answer would be `don't ever repeat that then.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one clean implementation you could use so you can avoid the usage of booleans for every single task you don't want to repeat:

```
var cache = [];

function do_once(task, fn) {
    if(cache.indexOf(task) == -1) { // shorthand: !~cache.indexOf(task)
        cache.push(task);
        return fn();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var alertLoading = alert.bind(null, "Loading...");

do_once("alert_loading", alertLoading); // will run

// later on...

do_once("alert_loading", alertLoading); // will not run again
```

This works as long as you give each task you don’t want to repeat a different name. Regardless of the function provided as the second argument to `do_once`, it will not run as long as `do_once` has already been called using the same task name.

Comment: Don't use shorthand. It obscures the intent of the expression. If you want something shorter, use `if (!cache.includes(task)) {`

Comment: Fair enough, but I'll stick to using `indexOf` in order to make this work in older browsers as well.

Comment: what is the ~??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: so basically, I can use do_once('task1', function) and do_once(''task2', function) without repeating them later on if i do do_once('task1') or do_once('task2')??

Comment: @freestylecoder the bitwise not operator is used in this case to convert `-1` to `0` and `0` to `-1`, so that the return value of `indexOf()` will be falsy if no match is found, and truthy if a match is found.

Comment: @freestylecoder Precisely, just make sure to use the same task name every time you repeat the task in your code but want it to run only once. The function provided does not matter, as long as the task name provided has not been used before, it will run the function inside it and never again.

Comment: @EternalDarkness thanks. this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to use a boolean flag.

But, if you have an aversion to `booleans`, you can do it by overwriting the function, thus ensuring it literally can never be called again.

```
function loadButOnlyOnce() {
     console.log('This will only happen once!');
     loadButOnlyOnce = function() {};
}

loadButOnlyOnce();
loadButOnlyOnce();
```

Your IDE will probably spew out warnings along the lines of "What are you doing, this is overwriting the function!". But it's your code, and you can do it if you want.

So, now you want a generic solution you can use with different functions? You can do this like so:

```
function allowOnlyOneCall(f) {
  return function() {
    f.apply(this, arguments);   
    f = function() {};
  }
}


function myMethod(p1) {
    console.log('myMethod is being invoked. p1 = ' + p1);
}

myMethod = allowOnlyOneCall(myMethod);


myMethod(5);
myMethod(5);
```

Comment: I want something that I can use with different functions. like I dont want to create a loadButOnlyOnce function every time i want to not repeat something.

Comment: @freestylecoder: OK, I've added a generic method to do this for you. This solution does not require you to identify functions by strings.

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable to store whether the function has already run or not (such as `hasRun`). Then simply store your functionality inside an `if` condition which checks that this variable is `false`. You would need to update this variable after running the logic for the first time.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
hasRun = false;

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!hasRun) {
    console.log('Loading...'); // Gets run once
    hasRun = true; // Set the flag to true so the conditional doesn't get entered again
  } else {
    console.log('The function already ran!'); // Runs every subsequent time
  }
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a factory function that memoizes the result of calling a function with a single [primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) as a parameter, you should use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const once = (() => fn => {
  const cache = new Map()
  return value => {
    if (!cache.has(value)) {
      cache.set(value, fn(value))
    }
    return cache.get(value)
  }
})()

function verboseSquare (value) {
  console.log('expensive calculation')
  return value * value
}

const squareOnce = once(verboseSquare)

console.log(squareOnce(4))
console.log(squareOnce(4)) // skipped work
console.log(squareOnce(5))
console.log(squareOnce(5)) // skipped work
```